# How to detect if iOS Wifi hardware is ON swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, gps, wifi

I'm trying to check if the WIFI hardware is on. I don't care if it is connected to internet or not. I just need to know if in the config the wifi is on. I need this because I will be using the GPS and I want to assure that I get the best accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enum ReachabilityType: CustomStringConvertible {
    case wwan
    case wiFi
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .wwan: return "WWAN"
        case .wiFi: return "WiFi"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes its best way to detect WIFI & WAN.

Comment: Hi there, I think that's just for knowing if the device can reach the internet. I don't really need to know if the device is online, I just need to know if the wifi is enabled

Comment: Hey, There is no boolean in iOS to tell status of your wifi. It is impossible to tell whether WiFi is on or off with the current frameworks. But as a developer, considering the odds of a user connecting to wifi and not having a network is rare, So I suggest you to use the network status.

Comment: I also have an another solution for this, You can determine the device if it is connected to internet via WiFi or Cellular, Depending on that you can actually ask user ti switch to WiFi if he/she is using cellular. (best option

Comment: Is this the correct solution to detect WiFi toggle status? If it is no the right answer PLEASE don't accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use this Pod: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift you can check whether you're connected via wifi or cellular or not connected

```
if reachability.isReachable {
   if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi {
     print("Reachable via WiFi")
   } else {
     print("Reachable via Cellular")
   }
} else {
   print("Network not reachable")
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I think that's just for knowing if the device can reach the internet. I don't really need to know if the device is online, I just need to know if the wifi is enabled.